# Read Console without break if something is written

Tags: java

how can I read everytime input in the java line? 
If a use a Scanner and another thread write something it will break. :(

Bad example:

```
Console output: (write hello)
helI'm a thread and I break your sentence!
lo
```

I know I can buffer the System.out, but it should read everytime, so when should I write the buffered output?

Comment: Scanner objects (usually) hold the execution untill you give them something. So, your scanner object may get input from your other threads.

Comment: You mean can you detect when there is an input from the console ?

Comment: Yea, the scanner hold it. If I write on char it spam everything which where holden ^^

Comment: use asynchronized method to print your output (assuming your scanner read a line and not every char separately)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this class:

```
public class Console {

private enum Mode { READ_LINE, PRINT_LINE, PRINT }; // TODO: add more Input & Output Modes
private Scanner scanner;

public Console() {
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
}

public String getUserInput() {
    return synchronizedIo(Mode.READ_LINE, null);
}

public void printLine(String text) {
    synchronizedIo(Mode.PRINT_LINE, text);
}

public void print(String text) {
    synchronizedIo(Mode.PRINT, text);
}

private synchronized String synchronizedIo(Mode mode, String text) {
    if (mode == Mode.READ_LINE) {
        return scanner.nextLine();
    } else if (mode == Mode.PRINT_LINE) {
        System.out.println(text);
    } else if (mode == Mode.PRINT) {
        System.out.print(text);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Do all you input and output to and from the console using these methods and the input and output shouldn't get mixed up.

```
Console c = new Console();
c.print("Input: ");
String input = c.getUserInput();
c.printLine("Entered text: " + input);
```

*Note: While you're reading the users input the print methods will block any calling thread.*